# Is it possible to declare the size of a global variable later?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int array[];

int main()
{
    int length;

    std::cin >> length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
}
```

This does not work since I did not declare the size of the array at the start of the program. However, I am not able to declare the size of the array since the length of the array depends on user input and I only get this input after I declare the array. (I require this array to be a global variable so I cannot declare it after declaring the length variable)

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` instead? You can resize it to your will whenever you want.

Comment: You seem to want a variable length array (VLA). But these are not supported in *standard* C++ (GNU C++ has them as an extension). As previous commentator said, used a `std::vector`.

Comment: The answer to the literal question in the title is: Yes: `extern int array[]; /*more code here */ int array[42];`. But I doubt that is what you were looking for. Use `std::vector` and `array.resize(length)`.

Comment: Not possible. The compiler needs to know the size of all variables. (`new` solves this problem *because it's not a variable*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare pointer to make it dynamic so length is allocated at runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
int* array;
int main()
{
    int length;

    std::cin >> length;
    
    array = new int[length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
}
```

after usage make sure to free memory by

```
delete[] array
```

Alternatively, you can use vector which will handle size and deletion automatically.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use array instead of some stl container you can use malloc and char*:

```
#include <iostream>

int* array;

int main()
{
    int length;

    std::cin >> length;
    array = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int))

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
}
```

This is more C than C++ but it certainly works.

Comment: Why `malloc` instead of `new[]`?

Comment: And you forgot to free the allocated memory.

Comment: Why `malloc` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Why `new[]` instead of `make_unique`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do dynamic allocation for this and then release the allocation

Comment: don't forget to `delete[]` the array when you are done using it: `delete[] array;`. Better to use `std::vector` though, as it handles these details internally for you.